# How do you do sp.record(sp.pack()) outside of SmartPy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I have a smart contract which verifies a signature from Bob in order to do something. The contract was made using SmartPy and for testing the scenario I used the following code to produce a signature:

```
bobSig = sp.make_signature(bob.secret_key, sp.pack(sp.record(gameName = gameName, bobScore = bobScore, aliceScore = aliceScore)))
```

Now I want to test the smart contract manually in tezos sandbox mode and I want to be able to serialize the data properly so that I can produce a signature using
`tezos-client sign bytes`.

In other words, how can I do the equivalent of `sp.pack(sp.record(gameName = gameName, bobScore = bobScore, aliceScore = aliceScore))` outside of SmartPy?

Comment: Or it'd be nice and easy if we could print stuff in the SmartPy test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several steps:

1. Produce a Michelson value for the record. It depends on the layout of the record and is shown in all SmartPy test transactions. (this is done by hand or with your language of choice). It will be something like `(Pair "aaa" ...)`
2. Pack the value by calling the client with `tezos-client hash data _data_ of type _type_` . `_data_` is the result of the first point, `_type_` is the Michelson type such as `(pair string ...)`. (I think)
3. call `tezos-client sign bytes`